# PopupMenu sometimes does not show on screen

Tags: java, android, popupmenu

I have a View which is contained in a Fragment. The View contains a number of "buttons" (Each "Button is an ImageView)(see screen 1)
[Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDFwk.png)

My objective is that when I click on one of these buttons a PopupMenu will appear (see screen 2)
[Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMQqy.png)

This is working well most of the time but on some "buttons", when the "button" is clicked, the PopupMenu does not usually show (although the toast message does appear indicating that the 'cick' has been registered).

The issue is apparent on the "button" in the top left corner and on buttons at the bottom of the fragment. Sometimes the menu appears (but usually after many 'clicks')

My working assumption is that, for some reason, the menu is not being displayed on the screen (I believe it is being displayed but is 'off screen'/not visible).

I have researched the issue but cannot find anyone with a similar issue.

I have tried different Gravity settings when creating the PopupMenu, but nothing made a difference.

The code I am using to create the PopupMenu appears to be classical.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer me on this.

**Extract from RemoteView.java**

```
// Constructors
public RemoteView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public RemoteView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public RemoteView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    rootview = inflate(context, R.layout.remote, this);

}
public class IconViewOnTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if (!edit) {
                        actionDOWN(v);
                    }
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    KeyMap keyMap=(KeyMap) v.getTag();
                    if (edit) {
                        if (movingButton) {
                            toIndex=keyMap.AMKeyItem;
                            toKey=keyMap.keyIndex;
                            exchangeButtons();
                        } else {
                            //popup edit options
                            if (keyMap.AMKeyItem  >= 0) showPopup(v);
                        }
                    } else {
                       actionUP(v);
                        performClick();
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

private void showPopup(final View view) {
        //Creating the instance of PopupMenu
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, view, Gravity.RIGHT, R.attr.actionOverflowMenuStyle, 0);
        //Inflating the Popup using xml file
        popup.getMenuInflater()
                .inflate(R.menu.edit_button_menu, popup.getMenu());
        Toast.makeText(context, "Popup Menu is visible",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        popup.show(); //showing popup menu
    }
```

**remote.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <com.andy.andymote.CommunicatorView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/remote_communicator">
        </com.andy.andymote.CommunicatorView>

        <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/buttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:numColumns="5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
            >
        </GridView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</merge>
```

**frag_device.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical"
>

    <com.andy.andymote.RemoteView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:id="@+id/remote">
    </com.andy.andymote.RemoteView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**edit_button_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/moveButton"
        android:title="Move"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/editButton"
        android:title="Edit"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/insertRow"
        android:title="Insert Row Above"/>

</menu>
```

**Extract from DeviceACTIVITY.java**

```
    private void loadFragment(){
        device = new DeviceFRAGMENT();
        device.setDevice(GLOBALS.deviceList.getDevice(deviceName));
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                device).commit();
    }
```

**Extract from DeviceFRAGMENT.java**

```
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_device, container, false);
            //Declare Widgets
            remote = view.findViewById(R.id.remote);
            remote.setKeys(device.getRemote());

        return view;
    }
```

**RemoteKeysAdapter.java**

```
import static com.andy.andymote.GLOBALS.iconSize;

public class RemoteKeysAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Context mContext;
    private final List<RemoteButton> remoteButtons;
    private _resourceAccess resource;
    private RemoteView.IconViewOnTouchListener iconViewOnTouchListener;
    private Remote remote;

    // 1
    public RemoteKeysAdapter(Context context, Remote remote, List<RemoteButton> remoteButtons,
                             RemoteView.IconViewOnTouchListener iconViewOnTouchListener) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.remote=remote;
        this.remoteButtons = remoteButtons;
        this.iconViewOnTouchListener=iconViewOnTouchListener;
        resource = new _resourceAccess(context);
    }

    // 2
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return remoteButtons.size();
    }

    // 3
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // 4
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    // 5
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Find the proper remoteButton for this cell by using the position index
        final RemoteButton remoteButton = remoteButtons.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.remote_button, null);
        }

        // create reference for the image in the XML layout file.
        final AppCompatImageView imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);


        // Set the image
        int indexOfAndyMoteKeyItem=remoteButton.getFromToIndex();
        if (indexOfAndyMoteKeyItem == -1){
            imageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_nobutton));
        } else {
            AndyMoteKeyItem andyMoteKeyItem=remote.getRemoteLayout().get(indexOfAndyMoteKeyItem);
            if (andyMoteKeyItem.getLircKeyItem().getIcon().length() == 0) {
                displayText(imageView, andyMoteKeyItem.getLircKeyItem().getText());
            } else {
                displayIcon(imageView, andyMoteKeyItem.getLircKeyItem().getIcon());
            }
        }
        KeyMap keyMap=new KeyMap();
        keyMap.AMKeyItem=indexOfAndyMoteKeyItem;
        keyMap.keyIndex=position;

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.gravity= Gravity.CENTER;
        params.width=iconSize;
        params.height=iconSize;
        convertView.setLayoutParams(params);
        convertView.setOnTouchListener(iconViewOnTouchListener);
        convertView.setPadding(16, 0, 0, 16);
        convertView.setVisibility(remoteButton.getVisibility());

        convertView.setTag(keyMap);
        return convertView;
    }
    private void displayIcon(AppCompatImageView imageView, String icon) {
        clIcon newIcon = factory.createIcon(icon);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(resource.getDrawableFromUri(newIcon.getURI(mContext)));
    }

    private void displayText(AppCompatImageView imageView, String text) {
        //https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable
        TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder().beginConfig()
                .textColor(Color.WHITE)
                .bold()
                .withBorder(4)
                .useFont(Typeface.DEFAULT)
                .fontSize(30) /* size in px */
                .endConfig()
                .buildRound(text, Color.DKGRAY);

        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, show the code where you call the showPopup() method.

Comment: Interesting. At this point, I'd recommend listening for the dismiss using `popup.setOnDismissListener()`, just to make sure that it's not happening immediately after the `show()`. I'm also curious to know, if you were to incrementally increase the `marginBottom` on that gridview (just to step it away from the screen edge), does the behavior change (with respect to the bottom buttons)?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. @greeble31 I have implemented the OnDismissListener() as you suggest and can confirm that this occurs when expected (ie when I click again anywhere on the screen). Regarding the margins. a value of 10dp appears to fix the problem on the bottom keys **but not** the button at top left hand corner. I tried values upto 50dp and experimented with left and right margins as well. Scrolling the view rarely (but sometimes) makes the button respond as wanted.

Comment: @Oleh I believe that the showPopup() method is shown in the' Extract from RemoteView.java'.

Comment: Needless to say, this shouldn't be happening, and all that this new information suggests is that we're missing something big. Are you using an `Adapter` to populate your `GridView`? Let's see the code for that. And how exactly is `showPopup()` being called?

Comment: You might try this as well: Add `+ view.toString()` to your toast, to verify that the view associated with a given button does NOT change, no matter how much you tap or scroll.

Comment: @greebie31 I have added the  Adapter code

Comment: and the IconViewOnTouchListener code into RemoteView.java

Comment: ref: add [+ view.toString()]. I get a(what looks like) a unique reference for each key _except_ when I scroll the view and manage to get the popup to appear the reference changes (ie the view DOES CHANGE when things work). when it stops working then the toast reverts to the old reference.

Comment: As a (hopefully) temporary workaround I am detecting when the first key is clicked and changing the anchor on the popup to the second key along. This works fine every time (but is not very elegant)

Comment: I can't spot the error. Let me give you this advice: Assuming that no buttons ever scroll off the screen, their views should never get replaced. Once your GridView finishes initializing, the views should basically be set in stone. `RemoteKeysAdapter.getView()` should not get called again. But it sounds like it _is_ getting called again. I would set a breakpoint on that and examine the call stack to try & infer what's happening.

Comment: @greeble31: Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using [Droppy](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjnquPHvMzdAhVICcAKHaHAB_YQFjAAegQIBxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fshehabic%2FDroppy&usg=AOvVaw3u_QzLs9NY06hBUO_0yFwq) instead of PopupMenu. No other magic was required

```
 private void showPopup(final View view) {
    DroppyMenuPopup.Builder popup = new DroppyMenuPopup.Builder(context, view);
    popup.addMenuItem(new DroppyMenuItem("Move").setId(R.id.moveButton));
    popup.addMenuItem(new DroppyMenuItem("Edit").setId(R.id.editButton));
    popup.addMenuItem(new DroppyMenuItem("Insert Row Above").setId(R.id.insertRow));
    // Set Callback handler
    popup.setOnClick(new DroppyClickCallbackInterface() {
        @Override
        public void call(View v, int id) {
            switch (id) {
                case R.id.editButton:
                    //code for editButton
                    break;
                case R.id.moveButton:
                    //code for moveButton
                    break;
                case R.id.insertRow:
                    //code for insertRow
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }
    });

    DroppyMenuPopup droppyMenu = popup.build();
    droppyMenu.show();
}
```